# Executing a PostgreSQL query with different specifications and saving results

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to run a query multiple times - each time with a slightly different specification concerning the "where" statements.
I would like to write one single query and to ask the database to execute each specification gradually and to save the respective output as csv.file. 
I have no idea how to start.

The basic query is as follows:

```
SELECT 
select id,
count(DISTINCT (a.id, c.publn_id)) as count
from a
join b on a.appln_id=b.appln_id
join c on b.publn_id=c.cit_id
left outer join d on c.publn_id=d.publn_id
group by id
```

I want to run the following additional specifications (note the modifications in the select and group by statements that are necessary in addition to the where conditions):

1.

```
SELECT 
select id, c.auth,
count(DISTINCT (a.id, c.publn_id)) as count
from a
join b on a.appln_id=b.appln_id
join c on b.publn_id=c.cit_id
left outer join d on c.publn_id=d.publn_id
where (c.auth='EP' or c.auth='US') 
group by id, c.auth
```

2.

```
SELECT 
select id, d.categ,
count(DISTINCT (a.id, c.publn_id)) as count
from a
join b on a.appln_id=b.appln_id
join c on b.publn_id=c.cit_id
left outer join d on c.publn_id=d.publn_id
where c.auth='EP'
and (d.categ='X' or d.categ='Y')
group by id, d.categ
```

3.

```
SELECT 
select id, d.categ,
count(DISTINCT (a.id, c.publn_id)) as count
from a
join b on a.appln_id=b.appln_id
join c on b.publn_id=c.cit_id
left outer join d on c.publn_id=d.publn_id
where c.auth='EP'
and (d.categ='E')
group by id, d.categ
```

4.

```
SELECT 
select id,
count(DISTINCT (a.id, c.publn_id)) as count
from a
join b on a.appln_id=b.appln_id
join c on b.publn_id=c.cit_id
left outer join d on c.publn_id=d.publn_id
where c.auth='EP'
and (d.categ!='Y' and d.categ!='X' and d.categ!='E' )
group by id
```

In addition, each specification will be queried for different time windows (but I leave these conditions out for now).

I would like to specify one single query that loops through all specifications and then saves the results automatically.

Comment: `UNION ALL` might be what you want? Possibly combined with a subquery in `FROM` or a CTE (`WITH` query)?

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure how `UNION ALL` could help, could you give an example? I am thinking about creating a temp table, then specifying different SELECTS with different conditions etc. However, I was looking for a solution where you only specify one basic SELECT statement with a loop containing different conditions. What I want to get is one CSV file for each specification: specify loop with conditions 'loop with where=(c.auth='EP' or c.auth='US'),  c.auth='EP'
and (d.categ='X' or d.categ='Y') ... , start loop using the basic query (applying the different conditions), save file afterwards

Answer (score 1):

Try to use special request `COPY (SELECT ...) TO file WITH CSV HEADER;`.

Like this one `COPY (SELECT * FROM country WHERE country_name LIKE 'A%') TO '/usr1/proj/bray/sql/a_list_countries.copy';`
Just add to internal request all parameters you need and run queries.

More info: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html

Comment: Thanks. COPY (SELECT...) TO STDOUT WITH CSV is working, but STDOUT is necessary because otherwise you have to be superuser. But I don't know where the resulting CSV file will be saved, nor do I know under which name. How can I specify this? BTW, I read that one could also use \COPY with backslash, but this gives me an error and does not run.

Comment: To output to a file you need a folder to which postgres is allowed to write. For example in `/tmp`, of course better to use a normal folder.
I think it would be more comfortable to connect from another host and output to stdout, redirected to a local file. Like `psql -h host -U user 'COPY (SELECT * FROM country WHERE country_name LIKE 'A%') TO stdout WITH CSV HEADER'  > file.csv`

Answer (score 0):

So, per clarifying comments, you want multiple output files. That was key missing information.

You cannot do that with an SQL query.

You *can* do it with a PL/PgSQL procedure - a function or a `DO` block - but only if you have permission to write files on the server, since you have to use `COPY` to a named file to write separate files within a `LOOP`. You'd create a temp table to pre-compute the results, then query it repeatedly with variants of `COPY (SELECT ... FROM temptable ... WHERE ...) TO 'somefilename') to write results.

Otherwise you need to do it with client-side scripting because the server has no way to specify a desired output filename for `copy ... to stdout` nor any way to split up multiple `copy`s within a single query.

For example you could write a script for running with `psql` that created a `temporary` table then used `\copy` to write the output files.

Or you could use perl's DBD::Pg, Python's psycopg2, or whatever client driver to query and copy the outputs.